# Matching whitespace and non-word characters in multiple lines using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

I would like to match '/s' and '/W' in multiple input fields. 
Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="fname">    
        <label id="fnamelabel">First Name: </label>
        <input id="fname" placeholder="First Name"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="lname">
        <label id="lnamelabel">Last Name: </label>
        <input id="lname" placeholder="Last Name"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <input id="button" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validateField()">
    </div>
```

Here's my javascript code:

```
function validateField(){
var wsrgx = /\s/g;
var chrgx = /\W/g;
var fnamestring = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lnamestring = document.getElementById("lname").value;
var result;
if (result = fnamestring.match(wsrgx)){
       console.log ("There is a whitespace character in the First Name field \nSource: " + fnamestring)
       return false;
       }
if (result = fnamestring.match(chrgx)){
       console.log ("There is a non-word character in the First Name field: \nSource: " + fnamestring);
       return false;
       }
if (result = lnamestring.match(wsrgx)){
       console.log ("There is a whitespace character in the Last Name field \nSource: " + lnamestring)
       return false;
       }
if (result = lnamestring.match(chrgx)){
       console.log ("There is a non-word character in the Last Name field \nSource: " + lnamestring)
       return false;
       }
}
```

How can I reduce the 'if' loops?

Thanks.

Comment: `if (result = fnamestring.match(wsrgx))`-> what is it? what do you want to get? This code ONLY sets value, returned from `fnamestring.match(wsrgx)` to `result` variable

Comment: You can't. (Glossing over the fact that an `if` is not a loop.) Each regex has a custom error message. But you *can* put everything (regex, input, and appropriate error message) into a single array of objects - at the very least it makes it slightly easier to expand with other tests.

Comment: @AndrewEvt My goal is to stop entries of whitespace and non-word characters. But, from what I see is that I will probably end up using a lot of 'if' loops.

Comment: @Jongware I don't prefer to index but thanks for your input.

Comment: Good news for you, whitespaces are non-word characters too. So use a single test and a single message.